# Score for Musette in C Major

Tags: classical-music, mozart

I'm trying to find a score (preferably written in Lilypond) for Musette in C Major. It's apparently in "Wolfgang's Music Book", number 14 and written by Leopold. I usually can find scores at Mutopia but there's nothing by L. Mozart (maybe I can be the first contributor!)

There's a Youtube recording at

Wikipedia has an article on Nannerls Notebuch but not Wolfgang's - [Nannerl's Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nannerl_Notenbuch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 23 in the IMSLP version.

[image]

https://imslp.org/wiki/Notebook_for_Wolfgang_(Mozart%2C_Leopold)

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

[Notebook for Wolfgang](https://imslp.org/wiki/Notebook_for_Wolfgang_(Mozart%2C_Leopold))